# Mock object for Authentication in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, mocking, testng

Now for the unit test I need the authenticate method to just pretend it worked correctly, in my case do nothing, so I can test if the method itself does the expected work (Authentication is tested elsewhere according to the unit testing principles, however authenticate needs to be called inside that method)

this is my TestNG Class where i need to make mock object for Authentication:

```
package in.hexgen.api.facade;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.hexgen.api.facade.security.HexGenPermissionEvaluator;

public class HexGenPermissionEvaluatorTest {
     private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HexGenPermissionEvaluatorTest.class);

  Object name="akash";
  Object permission="CREATE_REQUISITION";
  Authentication authentication;

  //@Resource(name = "permissionEval")
  private HexGenPermissionEvaluator permissionEval;

  @Test
  public void hasPermission() {
      //authentication.setAuthenticated(true);

      logger.debug("HexGenPermissionEvaluator Generate - starting ...");
         permissionEval.hasPermission(authentication,name, permission);
      logger.debug("HexGenPermissionEvaluator Generate - completed ...");
  }

}
```

How to do this.

Best Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering that the `permissionEval` object calls `authentication.isAuthenticatedFor(name,permission)`, using Mockito (https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) :

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*

...

@Test
public void test(){
    // Given
    Authentication authentication = mock(Authentication.class);
    when(authentication.isAuthenticatedFor(eq(name),eq(permission)).thenReturn(true);

    // When
    permissionEval.hasPermission(authentication,name, permission);

    // Then
    // Do you asserts/verify
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add @WithMockUser above your @Test method like this

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "user1", password = "user1", authorities = {
        "ROLE_ADMIN" })
public void testDeleteUser() throws Exception {
    User currentUser = createUser(1L, new Role(1L, "admin"));
    User userForDelete = createUser(2L, new Role(2L, "user"));
    when(userDaoMock.findByLogin(currentUser.getLogin()))
            .thenReturn(currentUser);
    mockMvc.perform(get("/admin/delete/{id}", userForDelete.getId()))
            .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
            .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/admin"));
}
```